# RegEx for string replacement

Tags: regex

I am a newbie in regex. I want to write a regex for string replacement which can be used in NotePad++ or any other editors which support regex. I want to replace the one in bold with nothing. Please see the below example.

**0d**12345678901234**p+123456789012**.0AA

12345678901234.0AA

Comment: I suggest [`^\d+[a-z]|[a-z]\+\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/WtvMqf/1). However, it is a guessing game with no specs provided. It can also be `^\d+d(?!\D)|(?<!\D)p\+\d+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the only possible pattern in your entire file? if so you can use ^(0d)|p\+[0-9]* pattern to search and batch replace it with nothing.